# Chrome bookmark javascript - popup to fill in part of URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm looking for a way to fill in part of a URL with a popup box.
Here's an example:  www.WEBSITE.com/12345/image.jpg

What im looking for is when i press the bookmark it will initiate a popup box, where you put a number which will insert it where the "12345" is on the example.

Sorry if i haven't explained this very well :/

Comment: By bookmark do you mean the built-in bookmark functionality (eg. the star next to the URL) ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is what i mean by the bookmark. http://puu.sh/mFmj5/a89111b60b.png

Comment: I think you can only access bookmarks if you are writing a chrome extension, not from the JS running on a page.

Comment: Well this script for example takes the URL and shortens it. So if you're able to take the current URL, you should be able to change the current URL: `javascript:( function() {var s = document.createElement('script'); s.setAttribute('id', 'postbookmarklet_js'); s.setAttribute('src', ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://s.po.st' : 'http://i.po.st') + '/static/v3/bookmarklet/post-bookmarklet.js?apiKey=95BE9D9C-2032-4C87-84B7-B2B753F18046'); document.body.appendChild(s);}() );`